# Something wrong with jquery watermark plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to implement this in my code but I don’t know what is the matter. I searched a lot but I could not discover where is the problem in my code. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.watermark.js" />
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" width="300px" id="input">

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#input").watermark("Heee");                              
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update:**

I have edited my code and still get this result:

[image]

My edited code:

```
<html>


<body>

<input type="text" width="300px" id="input">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.watermark.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#input").watermark("Heee");                              

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `$(function() { $("#input").watermark("Heee"); });`

Comment: @RUJordan Shouldn't need to. The script is at the end of the body. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Where is your jquery.watermark.js file located?   Same folder as your html?  Different folder?

Comment: @War10ck What is my console? Could you please give more further informations?

Comment: Most modern day browsers have a developer console to help you debug your site/scripts along with plenty of other features. Typically, the console/developer tool option can be found in the browser's menu (maybe under help or options). In most browsers, pressing `<F12>` will open the console as well.

Comment: @Charlie74 It is located the same folder as the html file. I‘m confused!

Comment: @A.Wolff Simply Watermark plugin does not work.

Comment: As a side note, the plugin doesn't appear to do anything useful in my opinion.  You can get the same effect using the `placeholder` attribute, like this:  `<input type="text" width="300px" id="input" placeholder="Heee">`

Comment: @Charlie74 Watermark plugin supports old browsers while html 5 placeholder does not.

Comment: Gotcha.   I see you're using Chrome to test.   If you press F12 to open the Dev Tools, click on the Console tab, and refresh the page...  any errors / warnings?

Comment: @Charlie74 Not at all. It’s empty.

Comment: Alright... please check my answer below from earlier.   I know a few suggested it may not work, but I feel it will solve the issue.   Let me know if you have any luck using the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always wrap your jQuery code around a document ready function, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#input").watermark("Heee");                              
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. The only advantage this provides is that it guarrantees initial elements on the page have rendered. By having the script at the body of the page, it accomplishes the same thing. The initial elements will load/render before the script tag is reached.

Comment: Op doesn't need to wrap this code here in document ready handler

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried with your code but i wont work, I added the head tag and use the ready function and now works well. I hope it helps. Regards

Regards

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.watermark.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputId').watermark('Required information');
});
</script>

<body>

<input type="text" width="300px" id="inputId">


</body>

</html>
```